# Dynamic DataGrid Header Text

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Have an application i'm coding at the moment, which uses DataGrid's. What i want to do is replace the header text with that from a column within an sql database.. Has anybody tried this or any idea on how it could be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do.

Fill a DataTable with data using an sql query(Easy and searchable on Google and Stackoverflow).

Say your query is

```
Select id, Emp_Name from emp;
```

Provide that Datatable as ItemSource to DataGrid.

Now your columns of grid will be same as that of your sql query. ie. datagrid will have 2 columns (id and Emp_Name)

Comment: in addition make sure that your `DataGrid` has the property `AutoGenerateColumns="True"` (it's set to true by default) and you are not adding columns manually in XAML.
Hope it helps